# Code snippets with personal templates

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, featured-questions

**I'll start with the question:** Is there a way to create a template for the stack-snippets?

I often find my self "building" a working code example with some boilerplate code just to demonstrate simple code (for an answer or a question).

This kind of feature would be great to have as I won't have to do it in external editors as stack-snippet doesn't have all languages and frameworks capabilities such as autocomplete, linting, etc.

Imagine you could have some predefined stack-snippets made by you, filled with the boilerplate code, and all you have to do is choose one.
Then answering or asking proper and well described questions would be a breeze.

Comment: You aren't really supposed to be doing this. The idea is that your examples will be *minimal*, not so extensive that they need to be built upon a template.

Comment: i often answer `react.js` related answers. most of the time i want my answers to be "run-able"  and to do so i would need to include some libraries and packages, write the root components and render it to the DOM. all this hassle and i haven't written a single meaningful line of code that relates directly to the  question. i can say the same thing about questions by the way. most of the questions has only small part of the code, why use the stack-snippet then? just format the code and be done with it. if you want a working example you need boilerplate code. i want to write it once! :)

Comment: Create your template, copy it to a file, save it to disk or a gist. Tada!

Comment: Yeah, but i would like the `Tada` thingy to happen inside stack overflow site :)

Comment: I find the same thing often answering knockout related questions and wanting the answers to be run-able. this would be a nice feature.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [UserScripts](https://tampermonkey.net/). Check out [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) if you need help.